# Entity Framework Core 5 dynamic table query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

With previous versions of Entity Framework, you could write a query with just a table name like this:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "." + "TableName");
DbSet dbset = dbcontext.Set(t);
```

Now with EF Core 5 and `dbContext.Set<TEntity>()` this is not working. How can I do the same in EF Core 5?

Comment: What are you trying to do that require the `Set()` method with the `Type` argument? What are you going to do with the `DbSet`, which has no type information?

Comment: I think you should describe your problem better because looking at it from every angle I can't see why you would want such a thing.

Comment: I have hundreds of tables with info for reports. User selects wich table and I need a way to easily query a table by name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you code like that as you could use other shortcut way.

```
dbContext.Set<TEntity>() is still working in EFCore 5.
```

Use like

```
public void YourFunction<T>() where T : class
{
    DbSet dbset = dbcontext.Set<T>();
}
```

or

```
public class YourClass<T> where T : class
{
    public void YourFunction()
    {
        DbSet dbset = dbcontext.Set<T>();
    }
}
```